# codeigniter database where or_where clause solution

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, where-clause

i dont know the codeigniter db translate of this sql query

```
select * from table
where a=1 and (b=1 or c=1 or d=1)

$this->db->where $this->db->or_where ?!?!
```

someone give me an help ?
thanks a lot
best regards

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the query you are looking for.

```
$query = $this->db->select("*")
         ->from("table")
         ->where("a", 1)
         ->group_start()
                    ->where("B", 1)
                    ->or_where('c', 1)
          ->group_end()
          ->get()
          ->result_array();

var_dump($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reed the [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=or_where#CI_DB_query_builder::or_where)

you can see that if you use or_where you will make a query like

```
$this->db->where('name !=', $name);
$this->db->or_where('id >', $id); 

// Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' OR id > 50
```

Comment: i dont get the same result of the query in codeigniter solution, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('a', 1);
$this->db->or_where('b', 1);
$this->db->or_where('c', 1);
$this->db->or_where('d', 1);
```